# Creating a union type based on a type where the key values are of a certain type

Tags: typescript, type-inference

Say I've got a `Person` type that is of the following shape:

```js
type LabelValue = {
  label: string
  value: string
}

type Person = {
  firstName: string
  lastName: string
  age: number
  pets: LabelValue[]
  details: LabelValue[]
}
```

I want to create a union type based on the keys in the Person type, where the values are of type **LabelValue**. E.g. in this case I'd want the type to end up as the following.

```js
type PersonLabelValueKeys = "pets" | "details";
```

Is it possible to do such thing?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured out it's possible by doing the following:

```js
type LabelValue = {
  label: string
  value: string
}

type Person = {
  firstName: string
  lastName: string
  age: number
  pets: LabelValue[]
  details: LabelValue[]
}

type PersonLabelValueKeys = {
  [Property in keyof Person]: Person[Property] extends LabelValue[] ? Property : never;
}[keyof Person]

const PetsOrDetails: PersonLabelValueKeys = "details"
```